# Possible compiler bug in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

Here is the situation:
I have created a custom view class with UITextView as its member. I make textView as a first responder after some event occurs.

```
@inteface MyCustomView : UIView{
   UITextView* textView;
}

- (void) doSomething;

@end
```

During program execution I send [doSomething] message to MyCustomView's instance.

```
[myCustomViewInstance doSomething];
```

What happens is very interesting, the program crashes by complaining that UITextView:doSomething is unrecognized selector.

Why is the program calling doSomething on UITextView (its member variable) instead of MyCustomView's instance.

What could be possibly wrong here ? (of course this is a canonical version of what I am doing but I don't understand in any logical error scenario this could be true unless something is messed up at compiler level)

What do you think I should investigate further ?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `[myCustomViewInstance doSomething]`. In the debugger console, `po myCustomViewInstance` and see what it says. Is it really the object you think it is?  (BTW, based on just what you've given here, it is REALLY premature to blame the compiler.)

Comment: Compiler for these types of errors are extremely unlikely. We need to see how you are creating your objects before we can see what the problem is. Also, @KurtRevis is right, use the debugger.

Comment: I highly doubt this a compiler bug. This could possibly have to do with memory management. Can you post more code? I.e., how are you allocating your object? How are you allocating your instance variable?

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted;  it is both a legitimate question and every programmer has to learn the lesson of not assuming compiler error some time.

Comment: You guys are correct I should have more confidence in the compiler than my code. Its 100% possible that I am somehow sending message to UITextView's instance. Now checking Class type to find more. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Objective-C doesn't have "member" variables, it has instance variables.   Minor thing; but terminology does matter.

Secondly, the crash is happening because `myCustomViewInstance` is pointing to an instance of `UITextView` and not your subclass.  This may be because you made such an assignment inadvertently or it may be because you have an over-release issue and it so happens that said variable ends up pointing to the wrong object by coincidence.

Finally, while there are certainly compiler bugs, it is *exceedingly unlikely* that such straightforward code would unveil a heretofore unknown compiler bug.   The compiler you are using is the very same one that is used to compile the umpteen millions of lines of code of the OS;   such a simple bug would very likely means no apps would work or, quite likely, the device wouldn't even boot.

That assumes that said line of code is actually what is crashing.

Comment: About the terminology : the best thing about being human is that we can still understand what is being discussed.

Comment: Certainly;  but using imprecise technology is confusing.  In this case, "member" and "instance" variable are mostly interchangeable, but precision is still helpful.